# checking if the line is Integer using Integer.parseInt()

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop, return

i am trying to read the line number of the file using the method Integer.parsInt() but there is error from the IDE in term of using Integer.parsInt() and IF statement together Note:file number is the number 1 and 2 on top of every line

```
1
00:00:01,600 --> 00:00:04,080
<b>Mr Magnussen, please state your
full name for the record.</b>

2
00:00:04,080 --> 00:00:07,040
Charles Augustus Magnussen.
```

the code i tried to use that give error the error is only flip if statement

```
public int lineLength() throws IOException {
    try {
        String file;
        file = "tra.srt";
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        Path path = Paths.get(file);
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset);
        String line;
        boolean r = false;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(line) != r) {
                return line.length();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return;

}
```

after changing the content if this code going to return the line number of each group of lines

```
     public String lineLength() throws IOException {
    try {
        String file;
        file = "tra.srt";
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        Path path = Paths.get(file);
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, charset);
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(line) > 0) {
                return line.substring(line.length());

            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: _"but there is error from the IDE in term of using Integer.parsInt()"_ And what is this error? Note that `r` is a boolean.

Comment: @ZouZou presumably using a `!=` operation on an `int` that is returned from `Integer.parseInt` and a `boolean` here `Integer.parseInt(line) != r`.

Comment: parseInt returns the `int` parsed. It doesn't return a  boolean.

Comment: First rule of programming: read the error message.

Comment: no error message my dear it say only flip the if statement

Comment: Why did someone -1 the question?

Comment: When there is a compiler error, a message is always associated with the error. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: i know brother but there is no message because this is part of my project the and message i get is run anyway

Comment: ok guys what i should write in the last return statement

Comment: now the error message are there can any one Check if the new code are returning the right line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(line) != r)
```

you are trying to compare an `int` and a `boolean`, as the IDE is telling you. This is not allowed in Java. You might want to compare the `int` with a number instead.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do exactly. Do you want the if condition to be passed if the int is > 0 perhaps? If so, then do that comparison directly instead, and get rid of the boolean entirely.

Comment: ok i did but take care of we are doing that to return the line number on top of every group of line first second what should i write in the last return statement

Comment: i think length method is wrong because i need it to return the line it self